# Instance member 'updateUser' can't be accessed using static access

Tags: flutter, dart

I am getting the error: `Instance member 'updateUser' can't be accessed using static access.` but I can't convert my updateUser method to static, because it is using TextControllers.
How can I solve this problem?

Error: `Instance member 'updateUser' can't be accessed using static access.`

**Using Future  updateUser:**

```
Padding(
                                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(
                                      8.0),
                                  child: ElevatedButton(
                                    child: Text("Bearbeiten"),
                                    onPressed: () async {
                                      if (_formKey.currentState.validate()) {
                                        await AuthProvider.updateUser('1xorAjA7hRZfOdN3zpkAWI7spgp1',_birthDateInString,genderSelected, roleSelected);
                                        _formKey.currentState.save();
                                        Navigator.of(context).pop();
                                      }
                                    },
                                  ),
                                )
```

**code Future  updateUser:**

```
Future <void> updateUser(String id,String birthday, String gender, String role, )async{
    return await FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('admins')
        .doc(id)
        .update({'username': usernameController, 'email': emailController, 'first name': firstNameController, 'last name': lastNameController, 'birthday': birthday, 'gender': gender, 'role': role,})
        .then((value) => print("User Updated"))
        .catchError((error) => print("Failed to update user: $error"));
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to access a method inside the class without creating an instance for the class. So you need to create the function as a static method or you can create the instance of the class and access it.

Changing the method as static.

```
class AuthProvider {
static Future <void> updateUser(String id,String birthday, String gender, String role, )async{
    return await Firebase......
  }
}
```

or Creating instances of the class.

```
if (_formKey.currentState.validate()) {
    AuthProvider newObj = AuthProvider();
    await newObj.updateUser('','','','');
    // or simply await AuthProvider().updateUser('','','','');
}
```

If you are restricted to the above methods, try creating a constructor for your class and access it like the second method.

Class:

```
class AuthProvider {
        AuthProvier();
        static Future <void> updateUser(String id,String birthday, String gender, String role, )async{
           return await Firebase......
        }
     }
```

On Event:

```
if (_formKey.currentState.validate()) {
    AuthProvider newObj = AuthProvider();
    await newObj.updateUser('','','','');
    // or simply await AuthProvider().updateUser('','','','');
}
```

Comment: Thank you for ur answer, but when I use AuthProvider newObj = AuthProvider();, then I am getting the error: The class 'AuthProvider' doesn't have an unnamed constructor. As u can see in this screenshot from my code, the class AuthProvider don't have a constructor (https://gyazo.com/2286193b83e9a05026354f193ddbcb31). So how can I create a instance of this class without a constructur?

Comment: have you tried the first approach?

Comment: I can't change the method as static, because I am using Textcontrollers (https://gyazo.com/c335d7855ddf67b992b485068a6c0dfb // https://gyazo.com/f872c2713898eea56ed12b216e6b3c39). When I change the method as static then I get the error: "Instance members can't be accessed from a static method.", because the TextControllers can't be static.

Comment: Then you can create a constructor for your class know? and go with creating a instance.

Comment: I thought I couldn't create a constructor , because I just knew how to create one with "const". With the TextControllers I couldn't use "const", so I had my problems. Now I found out it is possible to create one like this: "AuthProvider({Key key});"  - sorry for such a trivial question. I just started coding with dart.

Comment: added creating constructor method. hope this is what you are looking for. Happy coding.